# How to reset AUTO_INCREMENT in MySQL for all tables within a DB?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to run this or similiar AUTO_INCREMENT command for all tables in a database?

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Comment: I don't think you should edit your question if it is not directly related to the original question. Open a new question.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski ok I will... thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`t`.`query` SEPARATOR '; ')
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', `a`.`table_name`, '` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1') AS `query`,
            '1' AS `id`
        FROM `information_schema`.`tables` AS `a`
        WHERE `a`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'my_database' # <<< change this to your target database
          #AND `a`.`TABLE_TYPE` = 'BASE TABLE' << optional
          AND `a`.`AUTO_INCREMENT` IS NOT NULL
    ) AS `t`
GROUP BY `t`.`id`
```

This will generate a query for each table, but will not run the queries, so you will have to run the generated queries yourself.

Result will look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename1` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1; ALTER TABLE `tablename2` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1; ALTER TABLE `tablename3` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Comment: I think you have an error somewhere in the query as it returns  `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).`

Comment: Ok my mistake... I was watching wrong schema.

Comment: didn't work for me, are you assuming all tables have an id column?

Comment: Great, Thank you ^_^. 

BTW ``` WHERE a.table_schema = 'SCHEMA_NAME'  ```  not ```table name```

Comment: @GagBaghdasaryan fixed the query, thank you, should work properly now

Answer (score 1):

You can use xargs (replace `DB_NAME`):

```
mysql -Nsr -e "SELECT t.table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t WHERE t.table_schema = 'DB_NAME' AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'" | xargs -I {} mysql DB_NAME -e "ALTER TABLE {} AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;"
```

Comment: You might want to add `and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'`

Comment: Thank, can you also check my updated question, if that is possible as well?

Comment: Also MySQL does support doing this directly. You can for example do `select concat("alter table ", table_name...`, write this with `into outfile` in a temporary file and `source <temporary file>` it again. There are multiple ways to do it.

Comment: reset meaning remove data and start from scratch? therefore do a bulk truncate